# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] :

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a isloggedin middleware and when I put the isloggedin in any routs i get this error

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
```

This is the index middleware file

```
module.exports = {
  isLoggedIn: (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
  },
};
```

and this is my posts routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require("../models/post");
const { isLoggedIn } = require("../middleware/index");
// /posts
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.send(posts);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send();
  }
});

// /posts/new
router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.send("NEW /POSTS");
});
```

Comment: Typo: `isLoggedin` vs `isLoggedIn`. Flagged for closure.

Comment: No different the problem still show up

Comment: Are you sure the error originates in this router? Beside the already fixed typo looks good to me. In the error stack you should get a file name and a line number.

Comment: Yes i'm sure , because when I remove isLoggedIn from the route everything work fine

Comment: Alright, right after you require `isLoggedIn` try to log it and it's type. Just to make sure